# Surjectivity of floor of harmonic sequence

Tags: proof-verification, induction, ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

Define
$$H_n := \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac 1k $$

**The problem asks to prove** that the map $\phi:\mathbb{N}^\star \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}^\star $ defined by

$$\phi(n) := \lfloor H_n \rfloor $$
**is surjective (onto)**.

**I would like to check whether my attempt is correct.**

**Attempt (induction)**

- *Base case :* $\phi$ takes the values $1$ , $2$.
- *Inductive step :* $m $ being a natural $\ge 2$, assuming that $\phi$ takes the value $m$ (that is $m=\phi(n)$ for some nonzero natural $n$), we want to show that $\phi$ takes the value $m+1$ as well.

I'm going to use this well-known result as a lemma (*without proof*)

**Lemma :** $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^\star \quad \dfrac 12 \le H_{2n}- H_n < \dfrac 34$

Using the above lemma, we have two cases :

if $m\le H_n < m+\dfrac 12$ then $m+1\le H_{4n} < m+2$ yielding $m+1=\phi(4n)$.

if $m+\dfrac 12 \le H_n < m + 1 $ then $m+1 \le H_{2n} < m + \dfrac 74 < m+2$ yielding $m+1=\phi(2n)$.

In either case, we proved that the value $m+1$ is achieved whenever that the value $m$ is achieved by $\phi$.

That completes our proof by induction if no mistake has been made.

Thanks for any remarks.

Comment: I don't think that in the first case of your proof, the lemma gives you that $H_{4n}\geq m+1$, I think the most you can get from it is $H_{4n}\geq m+1/2$.

Comment: $H_{4n} = H_{4n} - H_{2n} + H_{2n}-H_n \ge \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 12 = 1 $

Comment: Ok, there was a $4n$. Then everything seems ok, the idea is and calculations

Answer (score 3):

Proof without the lemma.

Suppose that the map isn't surjective. Note that $\phi(1) = 1$.

There exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\lfloor H_n \rfloor \neq k$$

Since $\phi$ is non-decreasing, we must have $\phi(n)<k<\phi(n+1)$ for some $n$. But then we would have that $\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)\geq 2$, which is impossible. Indeed, $$\phi(n+1)-\phi(n) < H_{n+1}-H_n+1\leq 2.$$